# Ignore this user (everywhere) doesn't work

Tags: bug, chat, ignored-users

I decided to ignore a user everywhere in chat by using the "Ignore this user (everywhere)" feature, but I can still see their messages in the list of rooms in the chat user interface.

[image]

I chose to ignore badp, but I can still see the messages that they sent.

Comment: I would advise you to think carefully about the possible repercussions of ignoring a moderator, and also publicizing that choice.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox yes, i wish I had been more abstract with my question, what can i do to fix this situation? for what it's worth, i was just testing when i ignored badp, who as you point out is a moderator. i happened to notice the bug whilst ignoring a different user, who i will not name here